# Parsing string in SmallTalk

Tags: string, parsing, smalltalk

what am I trying is to switch each character in string with one next ( a-> b, y -> z, etc). Not sure though how do I do that in Smalltalk and tried to combine like that:

```
x := 'costam'.
y := x asArray.
y do: [:charr | charr := charr + 1. ].
y do: [:char | Transcript show: char printString; cr].
```

What I do is: iterate over array and increase each character.. though it doesn't work. I get error: attempt to store into argument. How do I get around that and do it proper way?

Now I got something like this:

```
x := 'costam'.
y := x asArray.
b := y at: 2.


n := 1.
m := 5.

[ n < m ] whileTrue: [
n := n + 1.
y at: n put: 'a'.
Transcript show: (y printString).
].
```

Problem that remains is how do I 'increase' characters like a -> b g -> h etc? 
SOLVED

Comment: The solution works of course only in the ascii range. There the numeric mapping of a character matches your expectations. If you leave that range it won't work. Well, it does not work for z, Z either. You need a definition what you "really" want to do. And you could see there is a habit by building derivates (collect: which creates a new string) instead of altering the source structure (the original string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x := 'costam'
answer := (x asIntegerArray collect: [ :c | c + 1]) asString.
Transcript show: answer
```

Comment: I got it somehow solved, thanks will use your answers aswell :).

Answer (score 2):

From "Smalltalk-80":

> Since argument names are pseudo-variable names, they can be used to access values like variable names, but their values cannot be changed by assignment. In the method for `spend:for:`, a statement of the form
>
> ```
> amount =: amount * taxRate
> ```
>
> would be syntactically illegal since the value of amount cannot be reassigned.

You can use the `collect:` message to create a new collection:

```
z =: y collect: [:char | (ch asciiValue + 1) asCharacter ].
```

`Character`s don't respond to `+`, so you'll need to convert to an `Integer` and back. Note that since `String`s are collections, they also respond to `collect:`

```
x collect: [:ch | (ch asciiValue + 1) asCharacter ]
```

If you want only ASCII characters, take the remainder modulo 128 before converting back to a character.

```
x collect: [:ch | (ch asciiValue + 1 \\ 128) asCharacter ]
```

If you wish to increment only letters and not other characters, add a conditional to the block.

```
x collect: [:ch | ch isLetter
                      ifTrue: [(ch asciiValue + 1) asCharacter]
                      ifFalse: [ch] ]
```

Note that the last block doesn't handle letters at the end of a contiguous range (e.g. `$z`, or, if the interpreter supports extended ASCII or Unicode, `$<16rD6>`), as the exact method depends on the capabilities of the system (basically, what's considered a letter).

Comment: asciiValue breaks it, message not understood :(

Comment: @mishe: are you sure you're sending `asciiValue` to a `Character`? What interpreter are you using? `asciiValue` is a standard message for `Character`. Your interpreter may also support `asInteger` and `value`.